# Unity C# scrollable GUI.BOX not working on android

Tags: c#, android, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have a `GUI` I am drawing when clicking on the shop button, there is `GUI.BeginScrollView` and inside some buttons, anyway, I have the scrollview working only in unity editor, if I run this on phone it doesn't work, I see the buttons but I don't have the scroller.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private bool PopUp;
        public string Info;
        public Touch touch;
        public Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;

        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                touch = Input.touches[0];
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    scrollPosition.y += touch.deltaPosition.y;
                }
            }

        }

        void OnGUI()
        {
            Rect rect = new Rect(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2);
            Rect close = new Rect(Screen.width / 4 + Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 4, Screen.width / 30, Screen.width / 30);
            Rect a= new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width / 2 - 2 * Screen.width / 50, Screen.height / 10);
            Rect b= new Rect(0, Screen.height / 10, Screen.width / 2 - 2 * Screen.width / 50, Screen.height / 10);
            Rect c= new Rect(0, 2 * Screen.height / 10, Screen.width / 2 - 2 * Screen.width / 50, Screen.height / 10);
            Rect d= new Rect(0, 3 * Screen.height / 10, Screen.width / 2 - 2 * Screen.width / 50, Screen.height / 10);
            Rect e= new Rect(0, 4 * Screen.height / 10, Screen.width / 2 - 2 * Screen.width / 50, Screen.height / 10);
            Rect f= new Rect(0, 5 * Screen.height / 10, Screen.width / 2 - 2 * Screen.width / 50, Screen.height / 10);
            if (PopUp)
            {
                GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
                float sizesc = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(Screen.width, 2) + Mathf.Pow(Screen.height, 2));
                myStyle.fontSize = (int)(0.015f * sizesc);
                scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(rect, scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, 0, PlayerPrefs.GetInt("unlocked") * Screen.height/10f + 10));
                if (GUI.Button(a, "Buy a", myStyle))
                {
//do something                 
                }
                if (GUI.Button(b, "Buy b", myStyle))
                {
//do something
                }
                if (GUI.Button(c, "Buy c", myStyle))
                {
//do something
                }
                if (GUI.Button(d, "Buy d", myStyle))
                {
//do something
                }
                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("e") > 0)
                {
                    if (GUI.Button(e, "Buy e", myStyle))
                    {
//do something
                    }
                }
                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("f") > 0)
                {
                    if (GUI.Button(f, "Buy f", myStyle))
                    {
//do something
                    }
                }
                GUI.EndScrollView();
                if (GUI.Button(close, "X"))
                {
                    PopUp = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public void onClick()
        {
            PopUp = true;
        }
    }
```

I can't understand why it works only on UnityEditor and not on my android device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was changing this line:

```
  scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(rect, scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, 0, PlayerPrefs.GetInt("unlocked") * Screen.height/10f));
```

which means number of buttons * height of button, to:

```
  scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(rect, scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, 0, PlayerPrefs.GetInt("unlocked") * Screen.height/10f + 10));
```

Just making the `Gui.BeginScrollView` larger a bit from the length of the buttons.